# Problem about conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

I have this problem

> If it is known that the probability of a certain judge arriving at a
>   correct verdict is the 95% and the investigation police (P.D.I.)
>   estimates that 99% of the accused are guilty, then, considering this
>   background, what is the probability that an accused, be really
>   innocent if the judge determined that he was innocent?

I can not solve it, but my correct development is:

$I =$ Innocent, $C = $ Judge delivers a correct verdict

$P(I^c) = 99/100 = 99\%$, then $P(I) = 1/100, P(C) = 95/100$

I need to get: The probability that he is innocent(I),  given that the judge said he was innocent, that is, that the judge is correct (C)

$P(I|C) = \frac{P(C \cap I)}{P(C)} = \frac{100 * P(C \cap I)}{95}$

But i cant get more.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: don't use "correct verdict" as an event.

The relevant events are $I$ for "is innocent" and $J$ for "is judged innocent".  After all, you seek the probability for being innocent when judged innocent.

$$\mathsf P(I\mid J) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(I)\mathsf P(J\mid I)}{\mathsf P(I)\mathsf P(J\mid I)+\mathsf P(I^\complement)\mathsf P(J\mid I^\complement)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The accused is not definitely innocent, he might be guilty.

This means you cannot assume he is innocent.

This means you cannot assume that "the judge said he was innocent" is the same as "the judge is correct".

You need to calculate
$$P(I\,|\,J)\ ,$$
where $J$ is the event that the judge says someone is innocent.